# how to fetch embed videos from facebook with its comments box?

Tags: php

I am fetching video from my facebook page through its I frame embed code on my website. but I also wants to fetch same videos comments plugin on my page. and when I comment on video through my web page. same comments shows on my facebook page inside videos comment plugin.  please help me that how I do this, this is my code to embed videos

```
<iframe 
    src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=603836463000637" 
    width="1280" 
    height="720" 
    frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Comment: How are you fetching Video, can you paste your code here ?

Comment: through this code

<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=603836463000637" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: yup... your directly copy pasting the things  ??

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/

//array of objects containing id, from, message, created_time, and likes fields.
http://graph.facebook.com/603836463000637?fields=comments

Permissions need : user_videos